# How to solve this error? "should be a triple of numbers, or a Scaled form."

Tags: graphics3d, warning-messages, list-manipulation, animation

Here is my code:

```
dX = 1;
dY = 1;
dZ = 1;
dS = 1;
v = {dX, dY, dZ};
xA = 2 * Pi ;
yA = 2 * Pi;
zA = 2* Pi;
fS[p_] := {{p, 0, 0}, {0, p, 0}, {0, 0, p}};
fRX[p_] := {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[p], -Sin[p]}, {0, Sin[p], Cos[p]}};
fRY[p_] := {{Cos[p], 0, Sin[p]}, {0, 1, 0}, {-Sin[p], 0, Cos[p]}};
fRZ[p_] := {{Cos[p], -Sin[p], 0}, {Sin[p], Cos[p], 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
cT[T_] := Table[
  v . fS[x * T * dS]. fRX[x * T * xA]. fRY[x * T * xA] . 
   fRZ[x * T * xA], {x, 0.01, 3.0, 0.005}]
Graphics3D[{ PointSize[Large], Point[ cT[1] ] } ]
Animate[Graphics3D[{ PointSize[Large], Point[ cT[T] ] } ], {T, 0, 12}]
```

Works when I evaluate it. But when I just load it or open the CDF player I receive this:

Coordinate $CellContext`cT[0.9079211235046387] should be a triple of numbers, or a Scaled form.

Would someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Quick fix is to use `SaveDefinitions -> True`.

Comment: where should I add this? To Graphics3D brackets?

Comment: Animate[Graphics3D[{ PointSize[Large], Point[ cT[T] ] } ], {T, 0, 1}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True] ---- this works now. THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

@Kuba solved my issue:

```
Animate[Graphics3D[{ PointSize[Large], Point[ cT[T] ] } ], {T, 0, 1}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Thanks again!