# How to solve "Coordinate should be a triple of numbers"?

Tags: functions, manipulate, graphics3d, warning-messages, animation

Something seems different with duplicated question "[How to solve this error? “should be a triple of numbers or a Scaled form.”](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127509/how-to-solve-this-error-should-be-a-triple-of-numbers-or-a-scaled-form)
", MMA tips may tell that `Abs` do not calculate? code reference from [Finding unit tangent, normal, and binormal vectors for a given r(t)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18598/finding-unit-tangent-normal-and-binormal-vectors-for-a-given-rt), but I have made some changes.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
r[t_] := {(1200 + 200*Sin[t]), (900 + 300*Cos[t]), (2000 + 
     100*Sin[t])};
uT[t_] = r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]];
vN[t_] = uT'[t]/Norm[uT'[t]];
vB[t_] = Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]/Norm[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]];
R[t_] = {uT[t], vB[t], vN[t]};

Animate[Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{r[t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}], 
  Graphics3D[{{Thick, Darker@Red, 
     Arrow[{r[s], r[s] + 100. uT[s]}]}, {Thick, Darker@Green, 
     Arrow[{r[s], r[s] + 100. vB[s]}]}, {Thick, Darker@Cyan, 
     Arrow[{r[s], r[s] + 100. vN[s]}]}}], PlotRange -> Automatic], {s,
   Pi/2, Pi/2}]
```

There are some errors with the running result, anyone can give some improvements would be appreciated, thanks!
[image]

Comment: It's from `Norm`.  You could use `FrenetSerretSystem` instead of your functions.  Or redefine norm. E.g. `norm[v_]:= Sqrt[v.v]` or `norm[v_?VectorQ]:= Sqrt[v.v]`.

Comment: @Michael E2, you are right,thank you!